# Append the script on one stage .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline

How to append the **script** section in one **stage** in the .gitlab-ci.yml file?

e.g in this example

```
stages:
  - stage1_name

.a:
  script:
    - echo "String 1"

.b:
  script:
    - echo "String 2"


stage1_name:
  stage: stage1_name
  extends: .a
  extends: .b
  script:
    - echo "String 3"
```

how to get as output:

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
```

instead of:

```
String 3
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gitlab 13.9 introduced a [!reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags)-tag which makes this possible;

```yaml
.setup:
  script:
    - echo creating environment

test:
  script:
    - !reference [.setup, script]
    - echo running my own command
```

Comment: VSCode would underline and display the error `Unresolved tag: !reference`. Folllowing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666177/cannot-get-reference-to-work-in-gitlab-ci-yaml), I had to add `"yaml.customTags": [ "!reference sequence" ]` in `vscode/settings.json` for it to work.

Answer (score 9):

You could use YAML [anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_specific_features.html#anchors) like this:

```
stages:
  - stage1_name

.a: &a
  - echo "String 1"

.b: &b
  - echo "String 2"

stage1_name:
  stage: stage1_name
  script:
    - *a
    - *b
    - echo "String 3"
```

Comment: This better than the choosen answer.

Comment: @JohnXiao the advantage of chosen answer with `!reference` tag is that you can reuse a script section from **separate** file. Which you cannot do with just YAML anchors.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this was:

```
stages:
  - stage1_name

.b:
  script:
    - echo "String 2"


stage1_name:
  stage: stage1_name
  before_script:
    - echo "String 1"
  extends: .b
  after_script:
    - echo "String 3"
```

To not overwrite the *script* section in **stage_1_name** I have use before_script and after_script.

Comment: Note that `after_script` is run even if `script` failed.

Comment: Also note that before_script excecutes in the same shell, but after_script excecutes in a new shell. This means the after_script may not function as desired depending on what your use-case is.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script

Comment: Also note that any erorr in the `after_script` is ignored, and does not make the job fail.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, when you use extends you will overwrite the entire block.

You can use dependencies like the @user3106558 example

Comment: I have got this "script2 job: dependency script1 is not defined in prior stages"

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about `extends` usage, but I'm using usually `dependencies` for such cases.

```
stages:
   - stage1

script1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
       //doSomething

script2:
  stage: stage1
  dependencies:
    - script1
  script:
      //doSomething

script3:
  stage: stage1
  depencencies:
     - script2
  script:
      //doSomething
```

this way, script2 will be started only after finishing script1, and script3 - only after second.

Comment: I have got this "script2 job: dependency script1 is not defined in prior stages"

Comment: This can't be true. `dependencies` can only refer jobs from prior stages, and it's only function is to limit the fetched artifacts from those jobs.